# Writing results of several cells in jupyter to one file (no overwriting)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, save, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook where I run the same simulation using many different combinations of parameters (essentially, to simulate different versions of environment and their effect on the results). Let's say that the result of each run is an image and a 2d array of all relevant metrics for my system. I want to be able to keep the images in notebook, but save the arrays all in one place, so that I can work with them later on if needed.

Ideally I would save them into an external file with the following format:

'Experiment environment version i' (or some other description)

2d array

and every time I would run a new simulation (a new cell) the results would be added into this file until I close it.

Any ideas how to end up with such external summary file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of try and error, here is a general answer how to write to txt (without pandas, otherwise see @jaybeesea's answer)

```
with open("filename.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write("Comment 1 \n")
    f.write("%s \n" %np.array2string(array, separator=' , '))
```

Every time you run it, it adds to the file "f".

Answer (score 0):

If you have excel available to you then you could use pandas to write the results to a spreadsheet (or you could use pandas to [write to a csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)).  See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), but essentially you would do the following when appending and/or using a new sheet:

```
import pandas as pd

for i in results:
    with pd.ExcelWriter('results.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:  
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Result'+i)
```

You will need to have your array in dataframe 'df', there are lots of [tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html) on how to put an array into pandas.